# Hide Action Bar on View scrolled

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've search anywhere but I haven't found it. Anything I've found this far is always hiding the Action Bar when a ListView, GridView or RecyclerView is scrolled. What I need is how to hide the Action Bar when a ViewGroup (using ScrollView for example) is scrolled? Because I can't really convert my layout to any of those three, and there is no onScrollListener for ScrollView.

Thank you.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30962301/1576416)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.implement ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener into your class, 
2.Write this line into your onCreate "getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);" (without quotes)
3.Now get ActionBar Height for Hide animation as follows -

```
    final TypedArray mstyled = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
mActionBarHeight = styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
mstyled.recycle();
```

4.Get Action Bar.

```
mActionBar = getActionBar();
```

5.Intilize scrollview.

```
((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.parent)).getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);
```

6.override onScrollChange and mode your method like this.

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
    float mfloat = ((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.parent)).getScrollY();
    if (mfloat >= mActionBarHeight && mActionBar.isShowing()) {
        mActionBar.hide();
    } else if ( mfloat==0 && !mActionBar.isShowing()) {
        mActionBar.show();
    }
}
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: How do I implement this for list view?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
```

instead

```
Scrollview.
```

It worked good