# How can I provide auto-hide/show toolbar, when scroll my recyclerview with coordinator layout?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

This is my layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.moskart.mosfake.activity.MainActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

           <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
               android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
               app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
               >

               <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                   local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                   local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                   app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                   />
           </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
           >

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
           </FrameLayout>

           <View
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="5dp"
               android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

       </FrameLayout>


   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navigation"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
       app:itemIconTint="@color/navItemIconTintColor"
       app:itemTextColor="@color/navItemTextColor"
       app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I set `app:layout_scrollFlags` for my `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `scroll|enterAlways` and expected that toolbar will work like in gapps (e.g. Google Play or Google Magazine) with auto-hide/show like on this sample:

[Google Magazine](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-IIGpxj-JZiM1JGbktKbHd4TXM/view?usp=sharing)

But I only got scrolling toolbar that does not retract automatically, but only if user completely scrolled it himself. See sample: [my app](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-IIGpxj-JZiRGdpTEc0WXplZ28/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my fragment with recyclerview, which I replace with `fragment_placeholder`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.moskart.mosfake.fragment.CategorySelectionFragment"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_horizontal_margin"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Search for ObservableScrollView , May be this is you want... :)

Answer (score 1):

You should measure if the bottom and top offset of the `AppBarLayout` is offset for more than the half the the height of the `AppBarLayout` and user has released the scroll. When this condition is fulfilled just start animating the translationY of the `Toolbar` or the offsetting of the `AppBarLayout`.

This could be achieved with custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavor` or with inheriting existing `AppBarLayout.Behaviour` and tweaking it to do so.

Comment: I have seen a similar approach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539623/android-lollipop-toolbar-how-to-hide-show-the-toolbar-while-scrolling, but I thought that now CoordinatorLayout provides this capability from the box.

Comment: I should create custom CoordinatorLayout.Behavior for my AppBarLayout or for Toolbar and what is dependency I should define in layoutDependsOn? CollapsingToolbarLayout? Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to do like this

[image]

take a look of this library

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

here is the example about how to implement it

https://snow.dog/blog/material-design-flexible-space-header-with-image/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NestedScrollView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView ...>
<LinearLayout ...>
    //Your Code Here
</LinearLayout>
```

Check this [Example](http://www.inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en)

Comment: unfortunately, this example works the same way as in my case.