# hide toolbar when scrolling recyclerview

Tags: android, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I am new in material design,I am unable to hide toolbar when scrolling list.For more information i am sharing my code is given below:

1.Common layout for app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <!--  <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/appbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


                        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/customToolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:textColorPrimary="@color/textColorPrimary"
                            app:colorButtonNormal="@android:color/white"
                            app:colorControlHighlight="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                            app:colorControlNormal="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_title_text_size"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:src="@drawable/btn_check_on"
                                android:visibility="gone" />
                        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
                    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/drawerIcon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_drawer_logo" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange_100"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/grey" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


                <include layout="@layout/horizontal_line" />
                <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
                   space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <moebel.de.app.ui.view.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                style="@style/MaterialSearchViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <moebel.de.app.ui.view.ShopFinderSearchView
                android:id="@+id/shopfinder_search_view"
                style="@style/ShopFinderSearchViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_progressbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/transparentColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_left"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/drawerListBackground"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_list_selector" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img_drawer_logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2.Run time adding fragment having this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filterLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/baseline">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/categoryLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/grey_100"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dotImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/baseline"
                android:src="@drawable/dot_image"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/categoryText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_filter_arrow"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/baseline"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_filter_arrow"
                android:text="@string/fragment_products_button_category"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_400"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/grey_100"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/filterDotImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/baseline"
                android:src="@drawable/dot_image"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_filter_arrow"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/baseline"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_filter_arrow"
                android:text="@string/fragment_products_button_filter"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_400"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1">

             <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/product_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                tools:listitem="@layout/product_grid_item" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listEmpty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Du hast keine Produkte auf Deinem Merkzettel"
                android:visibility="gone" />




            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_progressbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/transparentColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/transparentColor"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottomProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:background="@color/progressbarBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me to find out the solution .i am stuck in this problem don't know what is wrong in this code .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android lollipop toolbar: how to hide/show the toolbar while scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539623/android-lollipop-toolbar-how-to-hide-show-the-toolbar-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

After R&D i found that AppBarLayout must be the direct child of CoordinatorLayout So my corrected code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:elevation="0dp">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/customToolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                            android:textColorPrimary="@color/textColorPrimary"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"                                                       
                            app:colorButtonNormal="@android:color/white"
                            app:colorControlHighlight="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                            app:colorControlNormal="?                          android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_title_text_size"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:src="@drawable/btn_check_on"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


                    <include layout="@layout/horizontal_line" />

                   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange_100"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/grey" />
                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <moebel.de.app.ui.view.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            style="@style/MaterialSearchViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <moebel.de.app.ui.view.ShopFinderSearchView
            android:id="@+id/shopfinder_search_view"
            style="@style/ShopFinderSearchViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_progressbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/transparentColor"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_left"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/drawerListBackground"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_list_selector" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img_drawer_logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to your RecyclerView tag and the root tag of your fragment.

Comment: i have added layout_behavior according to you but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public abstract class HidingScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
private static final int HIDE_THRESHOLD = 20;
private int scrolledDistance = 0;
private boolean controlsVisible = true;

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

if (scrolledDistance > HIDE_THRESHOLD && controlsVisible) {
  onHide();
  controlsVisible = false;
  scrolledDistance = 0;
} else if (scrolledDistance < -HIDE_THRESHOLD && !controlsVisible) {
  onShow();
  controlsVisible = true;
  scrolledDistance = 0;
}

if((controlsVisible && dy>0) || (!controlsVisible && dy<0)) {
  scrolledDistance += dy;
}
}

public abstract void onHide();
public abstract void onShow();

}
```

And then add this Listener to your RecyclerView

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onHide() {
  hideViews();
}
@Override
public void onShow() {
  showViews();
}
});
```

In `hideViews()` method you can hide your toolbar
 
`mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));`

In `showViews()` method you can show your toolbar
`mToolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));`

Check this [link](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/) out for Complete Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to scrolling your toolbar, please redesign your layout.

`layout_behavior` effective only when `AppBarLayout` are children under the `CoordinatorLayout`

like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                   android:id="@+id/appbar"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```