# ListView doesn't scroll to end in TabLayout

Tags: android

I have problem with `listView` placed in one of tabs, when I scroll it down it's stops at half of last element.

I guessed that the problem is related with `AppBar`, because when I scroll down other tab with `scrollView` to the place where `AppBar` hides and I switch tab to this with `listView` it's scroll normal to the end. I've tried to hide `AppBar` in `OnCreateView` or on scroll list down but this doesn't help.

---

#### ListView when AppBar shown

### [image: ListView when AppBar shown]

#### ListView when AppBar hidden in other tab

### [image: ListView when AppBar hidden in other tab]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks you in advance for your help!

Comment: please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26547550/4363046

Comment: ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide(); in onCreateVIew() and the opposite one in listView.onScrollListener() helped, thanks :)