# Auto-hiding toolbar on scroll, when there are several other layers of views in-between

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I would like my activity's `Toolbar` to smoothly scroll out as a given scrollview grows, and then smoothly scroll back in if the user scrolls down. I.e. the basic `scroll|enterAlways` behaviour from e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187975/477476) answer.

However, my layout has some layers between the `CoordinatorLayout` containing the `Toolbar`, and the `ScrollView` that should be driving everything. Unlike in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41339801/477476), I'd like to have the following layout:

```
CoordinatorLayout
  AppBarLayout
    Toolbar
  LinearLayout [vertical]
    LinearLayout [vertical]
      ImageView
      ScrollView
```

The seemingly redundant two `LinearLayout`s are for background color control; and the idea with the `ImageView` and the `ScrollView` is that my UI should look like this:

```
+------------+
|TOOLBAR    =|
+------------+
|            |
|   IMAGE    |
|            |
|111111111111| 
|222222222222|
|333333333333|
|444444444444|
+------------+
```

which should then scroll to

```
+TOOLBAR----=+
+------------+
|            |
|   IMAGE    |
|            |
|111111111111| 
|222222222222|
|333333333333|
|444444444444|
|555555555555|
+------------+
```

and further to

```
+------------+
|            |
|   IMAGE    |
|            |
|111111111111| 
|222222222222|
|333333333333|
|444444444444|
|555555555555|
|666666666666|
+------------+
```

and then to

```
+------------+
|            |
|   IMAGE    |
|            |
|222222222222|
|333333333333|
|444444444444|
|555555555555|
|666666666666|
|777777777777| 
+------------+
```

(with the numbers representing the things in the `ScrollView`).

The above behaviour I was able to get just by setting 
`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` on the `Toolbar` as standard. However, if I then start dragging down on the `ScrollView`, the `Toolbar` doesn't come back. In fact, I haven't found any way to get the `Toolbar` back once it has scrolled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to use [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView), since, unlike its name suggested to me, it is not just for nesting `ScrollView`s into other `ScrollView`s, but also for nesting a `ScrollView` inside other containers:

> `NestedScrollView` is just like `ScrollView`, but it supports acting
>    as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android.