# Interaction of adjustPan and a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, android-nestedscrollview

In my layout, I have an `EditText` in a `NestedScrollView`. When the `EditText` is edited with a soft keyboard, I would like the `NestedScrollView`'s content to be scrolled up. However, instead, the whole contents of the activity is scrolled away, including an `ImageView` that shouldn't be moved:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

What I would like (bad Gimp-job):

[image]

The below is a simplified version of my layout that still exhibits the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:paddingTop="150dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa:Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa: Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa:  Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa:  aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa aa:  aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa  aa:  aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa " />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried various combinations of `windowSoftInputMode` on the activity and `isScrollContainer` on the `NestedScrollView`, but no combination gives me what I would like: when the soft keyboard is popped up, I would like the text to be scrolled up, without changing the `NestedScrollView`'s visible margin or the `ImageView` behind it.

Comment: have you found any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa:Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa: Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa:  Aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. Aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa:  aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaa aa:  aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa  aa:  aaa aaaaaa aaaaa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa " />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TRY THIS CODE 
IN THIS CODE I HAVE REPLACED FRAME LAYOUT WITH RELATIVE LAYOUT AND SET NESTED SCROLL VIEW BELOW THE IMAGE

Comment: But in my real app, I need the `NestedScrollView` to cover the whole activity, so that it plays nicely with [toolbar auto-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50275244/477476); which is why I'm using a padding  to reserve space for the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Scroll View Displays all the element which are present in it,

if you do not want to increase size of your editText the just keep its **fixed height**. ex 80dp

```
 <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" />
```

Hope after keeping fix height to EditText your problem will be solved

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if this solves your issue