# How to hide toolbar while scrolling listview up? (Just like google play store)

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Ok, so hiding the action bar is something doable. But, how can we hide the (newly introduced) toolbar in our activity?

I am making an app with an activity having theme as  theme.apcompat.light.noactionbar(to hide the action bar) , I have placed a toolbar with slidingtablayout below it. And below it is my listview.

What I want is to hide the toolbar when I scroll the listview up. But the slidingtablayout should remain there. And while in middle of the listview  if I scroll down, the toolbar should again be visible.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: @JaredBurrows not yet

Answer (score 8):

### Updated (8/24/2015):

Please see my latest answer here using the `Design Support Library`:

[Hiding the ActionBar on RecyclerView/ListView onScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559275/hiding-the-actionbar-on-recyclerview-listview-onscroll/17767691#17767691)

### Updated (6/2/2015):

### ListView + ToolBar - without Libraries:

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547550/950427 and https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java.

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
        mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
    }
});
```

From: http://pastebin.com/yeMX3VYP

### ListView + ActionBar - without Libraries:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767691/950427

I recently wanted the same functionality and this works perfectly for me:

As the user scrolls upward, the ActionBar will be hidden in order to give the user the entire screen to work work with.

As the user scrolls downward and lets go, the ActionBar will return.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {   }           

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {    
        if (view.getId() == listView.getId()) {
            final int currentFirstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
            } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
                getSupportActionBar().show();
            }

            mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
        }               
    }
});
```

Comment: @SMR you can do it exactly like this also when using ToolBar

Comment: Thanks! I understand its not `EXACT` but I am trying to help the OP in the correct direction.

Comment: Why not simply use ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true);?

Comment: @DareDeviL You can. This post was from Jan 2015.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

for recyclerView i managed it to make it like this:

```
public class FragmentsOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private final MainActivity mainActivity;
    private final View bothToolbarLayouts;
    private int approxToolbarHeight;

    public FragmentsOnScrollListener(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivity = activity;
        bothToolbarLayouts = mainActivity.getBothToolbarLayouts();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        approxToolbarHeight += dy;
        bothToolbarLayouts.animate().translationY(-approxToolbarHeight).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
    }
}
```