# Hiding Toolbar Android when scrolling down but not All Layout views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-scrollview

I have an Android Layout with a Scroll View Layout as Root, with  a Relative Layout.

Inside of this Relative Layout I have a Toolbar and a Text View and other children below.

How can I change this layout when scrolling down, the toolbar can hide and other children inside Scroll View as well, but not this specific Text View?

> - ScrollView
>
>   - Relative Layout
>   - Toolbar
>   - TextView (Visible even in Scrolling Down)
>   - Other Children...

Comment: are you looking for this https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager ?

Comment: @piotrek1543 Thanks for answering, but I'm actually need a way to hide the toolbar when scrolling down or substitute for other view while scrolling, maybe in changes in Layout file (order of views?) or dynamically. I'm working from API 10

Comment: If i have understood your question right. you can hide it by using android:scrollbars="none"

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037476/how-to-hide-toolbar-while-scrolling-listview-up-just-like-google-play-store

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539623/android-lollipop-toolbar-how-to-hide-show-the-toolbar-while-scrolling