# how to hide and show action bar while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a navigation drawer main activity and a search view above list view .what I want is that when I scroll up the listView action bar gets hidden and both the list and search view shift above providing more space to user (same as used by Google chrome etc..)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037476/how-to-hide-toolbar-while-scrolling-listview-up-just-like-google-play-store go to this link for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`  in Toolbar
you can see details [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **Coordinator Layout**  with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

Please refer this link - http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

**Good Luck**