# app bar not hiding when scrolling in android

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

hey guys Im trying to figure out on how to hide the app bar when scrolling down and reveal it when scrolling up. unfortunately no luck with my xml file. Ive seen some tutorial and used it but still no luck. I saw some tutorial that its achievable even only with xml, heres my xml hoping someone could help m figure out why it's not scrolling.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.serverus.oom.ServiceActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/app_bar"  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/service_content"
           >

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

and heres my gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `ScrollView` with [android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) - only `NestedScrollView` supplies the scrolling callbacks required for the app bar to hide prior to Lollipop.

Comment: I assume you actually have more than a screen's worth of content in your `NestedScrollView`? It won't scroll unless there's something to scroll.

Comment: yes I do have something to scroll. have you check my pastie? theres no content on it because Im creating the content dynamically thats why I leave it empty

Comment: Can you update to version 22.2.1 and see if that makes a difference? There were a number of bug fixes there around dynamic content.

Comment: I just finished updating but still no luck. 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}

Comment: I already found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007652/coordinatorlayout-does-not-hide-toolbar-on-scrolling-despite-implementing-all-re

"It seems that for some reason, scrolling with CoordinatorLayout does not work when using the <include> tag."
and someone already sent an issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175526

Comment: Solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer why it doesnt work. [CoordinatorLayout does not hide Toolbar on scrolling despite implementing all required parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007652/coordinatorlayout-does-not-hide-toolbar-on-scrolling-despite-implementing-all-re)
"It seems that for some reason, scrolling with CoordinatorLayout does not work when using the  tag."
and someone already sent an issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175526