# Android Hide ActionBar while scrolling in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar

I am looking for a method to hide actionbar like GooglePlay, when scrolling down and let the ActionBar reappear when scrolling up. I have found a lot of guides but them are about **recyclerview** and I am using **listview**.

The best guide I found is this: https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/FList" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my error:

```
Process: com.mycompany.test, PID: 6172
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.test/com.mycompany.test.activities.Friends_List_Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:684)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:428)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
                at com.mycompany.test.activities.Friends_List_Activity.onCreate(Friends_List_Activity.java:26)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
```

**EDIT:**
[Hiding the ActionBar on RecyclerView/ListView onScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559275/hiding-the-actionbar-on-recyclerview-listview-onscroll/17767691#17767691) 
In the guide above I can't use the code, I need to extend Activity so I am unable to use getSupportActionBar()

**EDIT 2.0**:

My activity:

```
public class Contacts_List_Activity extends Activity {
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private Contacts_List_Adapter_OBJ ContactsAdapter;
    private Menu menu;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Contacts_list);

        ContactsAdapter = new Contacts_List_Adapter_OBJ(this);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Contacts);
        listView.setAdapter(ContactsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_Contact_list_screen, menu);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                Contacts_List_Adapter_OBJ FilterAdapter = ContactsAdapter;
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                    FilterAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
                } else {
                    FilterAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toLowerCase());
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Set_MenuItem_Visible(false);
            }
        });
        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                Set_MenuItem_Visible(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        final MenuItem searchMI = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
                if (!queryTextFocused) {
                    searchMI.collapseActionView();
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the output above the stack trace? Did you add the Android Design Support library to your project?

Comment: @EboMike Yes I did and there isn't anything above

Comment: Did you start removing elements from your XML file one by one? Still seems a bit odd that there is no pertinent message whatsoever.

Comment: @EboMike I did but the error is the same; android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: can you post your activity code ?

Comment: @r7v With the activity code I create a  listview with a custom Adapter and the class extends Activity. There is no other

Comment: have you tried extending Appcompatactivity

Comment: @r7v the error still persists

Comment: I just triend using the layout you posted and it works fine. If you can post your activity code , I can check and post the answer

Comment: What version of the support library are you using?

Comment: where is Friends_List_Activity ?

Comment: @r7v Friend_List_Activity is the class (Activity)

Comment: @EboMike I am using the last version

Comment: The class you posted in your question is Contacts_List_Activity, not Friends_List_Activity.

Comment: i dont get it ?  you mean the file name ? can you post the import statements .

Comment: @r7v It was my fault, because I changed its name. There is only one class and his name is Contacts_List_Activity and is the activity with the listview

Comment: the exception is on this line (Friends_List_Activity.java:26)

Comment: @r7v This line is my "setContentView", the error is inside xml about CoordinatorLayout

Comment: I suspect something in your setup. Wrong version of support library, wrong version of support design library, wrong target SDK version maybe, just something in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried with the xml layout and it works :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

The issue in your case seems to be the base Activity. Extend your Contacts_List_Activity with AppCompatActivity

Updated layout - adding app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" to toolbar and 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/FList" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I made another project and with the xml and your code it doesn't work. The actionbar never disappear when scrolling

Comment: Did you add the  behaviour ?

Comment: Sorry, what behaviour?

Comment: add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to your listview