# Toolbar is not scrolling off even after providing "app:layout_scrollFlags" flag

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am trying implement Toolbar and TabLayout in which when you scroll the recycleview it should hide toolbar just like whatsapp application. I was referring google [Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and [Michal Z's Blog](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/). I have view pager in main activity and i am showing list of data inside it using recycleview.

Frankly speaking i was blown away by new google design library because with just one line of XML code it can change the complete UI and UI behavior. So idealy for this functionality we need to add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` line in toolbar and it just works. But for me its not working. I have tested it on API 19 and 21 devices.

By going through [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539623/android-lollipop-toolbar-how-to-hide-show-the-toolbar-while-scrolling) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559275/hiding-the-actionbar-on-recyclerview-listview-onscroll/27063901#27063901) on stack overflow and various [Blog](http://xmodulo.com/hide-show-toolbar-scrolling-android.html) [Blog](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en) i found 2 way to achieve this functionality 1. by providing scroll listener to recycleview and 2. by putting scrollable content inside `NestedScrollView`. But it didnt work as expected.

I think it should work without writing any code.

Main Activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ViewPagerFragment.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/order_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft= "true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtStatus" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: i am having same issue the appbarlayout was not scrollin on api 9 tablet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your layout seems to be correct.
Check that in your `build.gradle` version of `recyclerView` is exactly `22.2.0` and `buildToolsVersion` is `22.0.1`. You need to do it because all those new features appeared in the 22.2.0 version of support library as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Comment: buildToolsVersion is 22.0.1 but i was using "v7:22.0.+" version for recycleview. Now I changed it to 22.2.0 and it is working as expected. Thanks Arkadia

Comment: i'm using v7:23.3.0 but it's not working some time for me